# Using a vocabulary term as a panel wildcard

Tags: panels, 7, chaos-tool-suite

I want to create a frontpage **Panel Page** that shows **Views** according to a **Vocabulary Term Name** in the url, like so:

- *frontpage/persons*
- *frontpage/companies*
- *frontpage/institutions*

That way, I've configured my **Content Panel Views** to show content by that category.

The thing is, when I create my **Panel Page**, the only terms I can pass are:

- `Taxonomy term (multiple): ID`
- `Taxonomy term: ID`
- `Taxonomy vocabulary: ID`

And I need something like `taxonomy term: machine name`, but it doesn't appear within my options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a `validation rule` to *convert* your term name into a term id within your **view** as a `contextual filter`, and then pass the term name through the page.